# LINQ2SQL distinct count and sort

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a list of: `a,b,c`

Using LINQ2SQL I want a list of:
`a,b,count(a,b) sorted by a,b where intArray.Contains(c)`

The output can be groups of a, thats no problem.

To explain a bit further:
`SELECT a,b,c FROM TABLE WHERE c=1` would give me a list of a,b,c. I don't care about c, but I'm interesting in a distinct list of a,b and the count of a,b.

Ok, not the best explanation. Hope you understand. Sample data:

```
The data
1,1,1
0,0,0
0,1,0
0,1,1
0,2,0
0,3,5
0,3,6
0,3,7

Should output
0,0,1
0,1,2
0,2,1
0,3,3
1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from data in context.Data
group data by new
{
  data.A,
  data.B,
} into dg
orderby dg.Key.A, dg.Key.B
select new
{
  dg.Key.A,
  dg.Key.B,
  dg.Count()
}
```

Comment: Missing something between 'group' and 'by'? What about sorting?

Comment: could add `orderby dg.Key.A, dg.Key.B` after dg and before select for that